# How to remove Cc or Bcc in MFMailIComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I don't want include cc or bcc fields in mail composer sheet ..

Can anybody knows how can  I do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove them.

There is very little you can change about the *look* of this dialog.

Comment: How much of the look I can change ? Can you give any reference doc ?

Comment: The only reference is the Apple one: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html.

In another question people have proposed hacks to make changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737848/change-title-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller. However, I would strongly discourage this as you will almost certainly get rejected. The three20 framework has a mail composer interface that might be more customisable.

Answer (score 1):

As lyon mentions, the changes you can do to the looks of this dialog is almost none.

There is a sample code from Apple which you can try and play around. It is called MailComposer.

I just tried to pass nil for cc and bcc like this for you but it didnt work:

```
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:nil];   
[picker setBccRecipients:nil];
```