# Changing the title of a MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Although i know changing `MFMailComposeViewController` is fround upon, i'm taking a risk.
I found some ideas such as

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; // Existing line
[[[[controller viewControllers] lastObject] navigationItem] setTitle:@"SomethingElse"];
```

and

```
[[[[(MFMailComposeViewController*)vc  navigationBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@" SomethingElse"];
```

but the odd thing is that the title is "SomethingElse" for like 2 seconds and after that it returns to the subject that is set. I've tried other solutions as well but the same output.

I am using SHK (ShareKit) to connect to social. Here is the code from `showViewController` :

```
if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(modalPresentationStyle)])
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = [SHK modalPresentationStyle];

    if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(modalTransitionStyle)])
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = [SHK modalTransitionStyle];

[topViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

 [[[[(MFMailComposeViewController*)vc  navigationBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@" "];



[(UINavigationController *)vc navigationBar].barStyle = 
    [(UINavigationController *)vc toolbar].barStyle = [SHK barStyle];



    self.currentView = vc;
```

Comment: Check the SO post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737848/change-title-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is some kind of protection came with iOS4.

It is clearly stated here that you MUST NOT change the interface provided by Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

***Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.***

I knew some people being rejected because of this. I just wanted to warn you about this.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i think i'm gonna stick with not modifying anything :)

Comment: That's why I hate Apple. If they can't let us customise the interface, they should at least provide something that looks good. Right now my title is looking like "Queries from clie...". Such an ugly title :-@

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the mail subject. Means `[MFMailComposeViewController setsubject:@"yourTitle"]`. Then this will be shown as a titile .but if you do not write anything in `MFMailComposeViewController` subject then by default it can show "New Message".