# Set the title of MFMailComposeViewController to NIL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Does anyone know how to change the title of MFMailComposeViewController to @"" but it never changes.
I have the following code written:

```
NSString *currentVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currentVersion isEqualToString:@"5.0"]) {
        [mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@""];
       [mailComposeViewController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[AppDelegate appDelegate] navBarBackgroundImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, your trying to add a title to your `UINavigationBar`, which can be done like this...

```
UINavigationItem* item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title text"];
```

EDIT: It doesn't seem to be possible, at least not if you want the app to be approved...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401390/716216

Comment: how to add on the mailcomposeviewcontroller ? I know I can add a title to a navigationcontroller but how to add on mailcomposeviewcontroller?