# Suppress "Save Draft" button in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, button, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController inside an iphone app and it works fine.

When I press the "Cancel" button, an action sheet with the options "Delete Draft" (red), "Save Draft"(white) and "Cancel"(black) is prompted.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to suppress the "Save Draft" button? I control programmatically the flow of information and will possibly loose the control, if a mail is pushed into the "Drafts" folder.
2. Is it possible to change the colors of the appearing buttons?

Comment: 3. Is it possible to read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: I did it. But sometimes people know more than officially documented!!

Comment: Nick, a lot of default iOS behaviors and controls can be changed using methods that aren't officially documented. A lot of the times these methods don't involve private APIs, so TomThumb's question is perfectly valid.

Comment: To quote... "**Important** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application." I don't think there is any ambiguity there.

Comment: @Nick: You're right.
To tell the truth, I expected something similar to the answers of 
[Change title of MFMailComposeViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737848/change-title-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this not feasible because its functionality is default MFMailCompose class.So you can not change it.

You can change only navigation bar and buttons tint color

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[[controller navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.36 green:0.09 blue:0.39 alpha:1.00]];
```